# Make a process "return" an integer

Tags: c, process

I want a process to return a status, but I might need a bigger integer type, like a 64 bit integer on every system. What is the best way to "return" a bigger integer to the parent process. The solution should also be portable to all posix systems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about describing the *real* problem instead? Why do you need it?

Comment: Print it out to STDOUT

Comment: There are lots of options depending on what you actually want to accomplish. For example, the value could be written to `stdout` if the rest of your processing pipeline can consume that (e.g. if you are piping this program's output into another one).

Comment: The exit status is intended to return a *status*, which is typically just success/fail, with perhaps a handful of distinct failure reasons.  If you need something more, "like a 64 bit integer", that sounds like you're returning *data*, *information*, not just a status.  But since the exit status wasn't designed for returning arbitrary data, you're probably going to have extreme difficulties trying to wedge data through it that it was never intended to handle.